# When using grep, how to ensure that the search string begins at the start of a line (excluding whitespace)?

Tags: grep

I have the following grep query

```
 $ grep -nr "ActiveChild\s*=" .
```

This finds all instances of ActiveChild followed by whitespace-

```
 ActiveChild = "ABC"
    ActiveChild = "PQR"
 ActiveChild = "XYZ"
```

However, it also gives me results like

```
 If ActiveChild = "LMN" Then
```

I want to avoid the above case. I want to ensure that "ActiveChild" is the first word that appears on the line that I am searching. It doesn't matter if there is whitespace before it. Unfortunately, writing something like

```
 grep -nr "\s*ActiveChild\s*=" .
```

doesn't help at all. How can I write such a query? Also, is "query" the right word, or is something else used in the context of grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kent$  cat test
 ActiveChild = "ABC"
    ActiveChild = "PQR"
 ActiveChild = "XYZ"
 If ActiveChild = "LMN" Then

kent$  grep -E '^\s*ActiveChild\s*=' test
 ActiveChild = "ABC"
    ActiveChild = "PQR"
 ActiveChild = "XYZ"
```

Comment: Why the option for Extended Regular Expression?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. So ^ ensures that it begins at the start of the line.